# How to turn "Hey Siri" on and off automatically on macOS

Tags: siri

I have a colleague whose name has a couple of the same sounds as "Siri", and when I greet her in Zoom meetings with "Hey ", Siri virtually always responds, interrupting.  It was funny the first time, but got annoying quickly, and I had to turn off listening for "Hey Siri" because of this constant annoying failure of Apple's software to properly distinguish between two names that a human would never confuse (unless there were background noise).

This is unfortunate, because being able to delegate certain tasks to Siri would be useful, but going in and manually switching it all the time is extremely tedious and almost always forgotten.

SO how can I schedule a command to switch "Hey Siri" off before my meetings and back on afterward.  In other words, what is the command--whether AppleScript or JavaScript or shell script?

Comment: So a script that disables Siri, then starts the program. Or a script that checks in program X is running and disables Siri if it is.

Comment: A script that turns off 'Listen for "Hey Siri"' without me (1) clicking the  menu, (2) choosing System Preferences, (3) choosing Siri, (4) and unchecking 'Listen for "Hey Siri"'.  Nothing more nor nothing less are necessary.  Once I know how to turn it off, how to turn it on should likely be obvious.